# MATLAB, Phased Array Toolbox and `pattern` function

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to understand an [example](http://www.mathworks.com/help/phased/examples/subarrays-in-phased-array-antennas.html) for MATLAB Phased Array Toolbox.

There is called function `pattern`:

```
pattern(ha,fc,-180:180,0,'Type','powerdb',...
    'CoordinateSystem','rectangular','PropagationSpeed',c)
```

Cannot you tell me, where is the function described and what does it do?

Answer (score 0):

pattern is a method on antenna array objects. ha is an instance of the class phased.ReplicatedSubarray. When object is the first argument to a call, MATLAB first checks whether this is a method on that object and calls that. This syntax is same as calling ha.pattern(...). If you try methods(ha) it should list pattern as one of the methods. You can find documentation for pattern method of this object at http://www.mathworks.com/help/phased/ref/phased.replicatedsubarray.pattern.html.

Comment: Thank you, comrade, but I've already realized, that it's for 2015a version, while I have only 2014b.
Also, don't you know a way to switch to 2014b version of online documentation?